# Network Plot - R - Modify Col

Tags: r, visualization

Having this R statement:

```
itemsets = apriori(data, parameter=list(support=0.05, confidence=0.5))
plot(itemsets, method="graph", 
     control=list(type="items"))
```

How can I change the colour of my plot? I try to insert "col" but don't allows me to do that because I'm getting the following error:

```
Error in i.parse.plot.params(graph, list(...)) : 
  Unknown plot parameters: col
```

thanks

Comment: Hey, welcome to DataScience-SE. Please, mention the error message you're getting. It will help in sorting it out. Cheers!

Comment: @AbhishekJaiswal thanks for your comment. I updated the post wit the error :) Yes, I try with "col = "red" " statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `edgeCol` and `nodeCol`:

```
library("arulesViz")
data(Groceries)
rules <- apriori(Groceries, parameter=list(support=0.005, confidence=0.5))
plot(rules, method="graph",
     control=list(nodeCol="yellow", edgeCol="blue", type="items"))
```

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, try this--

```
itemsets = apriori(data, parameter=list(support=0.05, confidence=0.5))
plot(itemsets, method="graph", 
     control=list(type="items", col="red"))
```

Cheers!

Comment: thanks for your answer. The code runs well but my chart still have the same colour even if I change to green or blue. Do you know why? I'm using RStudio